# Binding Combobox SelectedValue from bound value in UserControl grid

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, selectedvalue

I've spent the last two days trying to make this happen, and I can't figure out what I am missing.  I have a WPF user control with a grid and within that grid are text boxes and comboboxes.  The DataContext of the grid is set in C# code with an object, and I've been able to two-way bind my text boxes to the grid's DataContext object.  Here is some sample code.  The object that is going into the ClinicInfoRoot is my Clinic object and one of it's properties is StateID (which is important in a moment)

```
private void Events_ClinicSelected( object sender, ClinicSelectedEventArgs e )
{
    if ( !DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode( this ) )
    {
        // Get the current logged in user object from arguments and set local
        this.CurrentLoggedInPDUser = e.CurrentLoggedInPDUser;

        // Bind the patient object to the window grid data context
        this.ClinicInfoRoot.DataContext = e.Clinic;

        // Set the mode and call mode manager
        this.SetMode( Mode.View );
        this.ModeManager();
    }
}
```

Now for xaml:

```
<Grid Name="ClinicInfoRoot" 
  Margin="0,0,10,10" 
  Validation.Error="ClinicInfoRoot_Error">

<TextBox Margin="82,28,0,0" 
         Name="txtName" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Width="82" >

    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Name" 
                 Mode="TwoWay" 
                 ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" 
                 ValidatesOnExceptions="True" 
                 NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"></Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="281,141,0,0" 
          Name="cbState" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="73" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Abbrev" 
          SelectedValuePath="StateID" >
    <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
        <Binding ElementName="ClinicInfoRoot" 
                 Path="Clinic.StateID" 
                 Mode="TwoWay" 
                 ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" 
                 ValidatesOnExceptions="True" 
                 NotifyOnValidationError="True" 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"></Binding>
    </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
</ComboBox>
```

I have been able to bind the textbox with the appropriate properties from the Clinic object, but the issue is with my State combobox.  I have bound the ItemsSource with a list of states from another object, and the combobox fills correctly.  However, I want the StateID property in the Clinic object to set what is showing in the combobox, but I can't figure out what the ElementName and Path properties should be for the SelectedValue.

What is the syntax for the ElementName and Path in the binding for the SelectedValue of my combobox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XAML is confusing, partly because you are writing bindings the long way, however if everything is working then I suspect you're just missing the `DataContext` in your binding `Path`

Here's an example

ViewModel:

```
List<State> States;
Clinic SelectedClinic;
```

Where `State` has two properties

```
string Abbrev
int StateId
```

And `Clinic` has two properties

```
string Name
int StateId
```

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="SomePanel" DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel}">

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedClinic}">

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />

        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=SomePanel, Path=DataContext.States}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Abbrev" 
                  SelectedValuePath="StateID"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding StateId}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Few things to note here

- The Parent Grid's DataContext is the ViewModel. The child Grid gets it's DataContext bound to SelectedClinic, which is the Clinic Object. This allows the binding for `TextBox.Text` and `ComboBox.SelectedValue` to work.
- To bind the ComboBox's ItemsSource, I am using `ElementName` to point the binding to the UI object named `SomePanel`, and then telling it to bind to `DataContext.States`. This means the final binding for the ItemsSource is pointing to `SomePanel.DataContext.States`.

Comment: Rachel, Thanks for your answer.  It seems that adding another grid to my user control is what you are suggesting if I understand correctly.  I am not using a ViewModel, so I'm not sure why I should create another grid and bind it to my list of states when I already have them bound.  In the second grid when you have the DataContext={Binding SelectedClinic}, how do I represent that in my page behind?  Do I create a public property and assign my Clinic object to that and then instead of setting the DataContext in my page behind, do it only in xaml?

Comment: Rachel, I think I just got what you were trying to help me understand.  Basically, your ViewModel has a number of objects in it, lists, singular objects, whatever has to be bound to the window.  Then, because I can point to two different sources in the combobox, the ItemsSource and the SelectedValue binding works.  Previously there was no way to distinguish what came from where.  So to extend your model out, If I had a selected object and several combo boxes, I'd bind them all to the outer grid.  Then the selected object with all of its detail properties would be bound to an inner grid.

Comment: @MikeMalter Yes, that's the rough idea. The outer Grid doesn't necessarily have to be a Grid either. It can be another Panel, Control, or even your Window object. You also don't really need a ViewModel, however I always found WPF easier to work with using the MVVM design pattern. The important part is that your ComboBox's DataContext should be your Clinic object so you can bind the SelectedValue, and it should know where to go to find it's ItemsSource, whether that be a RelativeSource Binding, StaticResource, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you do have your DataContext set up correctly as you claim, then just remove the `ElementName` from the binding. That is used for binding to another UIElement, and you don't have any UIElements called `ClinicInfoRoot`.

Comment: Thanks Slugster for your answer.  Actually I did just try removing the ElementName property in the SelectedValue Binding tag, but it still would not show the correct state.  If I set the SelectedValue explicitly right after setting the DataContext in the grid, the correct state will show.  So the value of StateID is good.  I just can't get it to bind.  Any other thoughts?